# Sequential Padded Numerical Prefix, Underscore, Copied to New Folder Based On txt List Of Files

Tags: batch-file, copy, text-files, filenames, sequential

I'm really close, I think. I'm not great at this kind of stuff, but I've cobbled together code I found searching here. Maybe you can figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I've got:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set /p "number=Please enter the starting control number:" || goto :eof

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (List.txt) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%b in (!number!) do (
        endlocal
         echo copy "%%~fa" "c:\myfolder\%%b_%%~nx"
    )
    set /a "number+=1"
)
```

So far it outputs as needed, except the file isn't created with theoriginal name at the end. It actually suffixes "%~nx" as text.

Essentially, I want it to take the original file, tack on a prefix, counting up from a provided number, padded (this part I haven't worked on yet), into a new folder.

Thanks for reading!

Here's what I neded up with:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /p "dir=Set output dir:" || goto :eof

set /p "d=Set total digits:" || goto :eof
set number=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in (List.txt) do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%b in (!number!) do (
    set "pad=0000000000%%b"
    set "name=!pad:~-%d%!
     copy "%%~fa" "%dir%\!name!_%%~nxa"
)
set /a "number+=1"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`~nx` is the name of a variable called `x`. Perhaps you meant either `~nxa` or `~nxb` which is name and extension of your two `for` variables.

Why is there an EndLocal in the middle of a loop?

Comment: Ah! Yes! Thank you! And to answer your question, I have no idea. It was there on the code I was Frankensteining, so I left it in.

Comment: It does... Honestly, I know very little of this kind of thing. I'm just good at cobbling.